# Wildfly deployment scanner

Tags: deployment, wildfly, autodeploy

I am new to WildFly and I am trying to know more on deployment scanner process.

There are two deployment mode in WildFly auto deploy mode and manual.

If I restart WildFly, my ear files are deploying again. As per WildFly forum it should deploy again if there is a change in file(based on time-stamp).

I am running my WildFly in standalone mode.

When I run the following command:

```
sh standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

and its started within 2 minutes. Again if I restart server is taking same time.

Answer (score 2):

It is re-deployed using timestamp only in a running instance. An application needs to be deployed to 'run' thus when the servcer starts it deploys the applications and stops aka undeploys them when it stops.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you deploy anything on wildfly manually ( I mean using admin console ) , it put a entry in standalone.xml ( or other xml if you configure to use them ). You will find an entry referring to it. With this during next restart it knows what to re-deploy.

In scanner mode , it know location of scanner directory and during startup , it picks content from it.

Now for >>>>> As per WildFly forum it should deploy again if there is a change in file(based on time-stamp).

Ans : If autodeployed is true ; then while server is running and you update any file , it will be picked up and wildfly will re-deploy app.

Hope this helps